# Kendo UI MVC DropDownList

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I am trying to learn the Kendo UI. I created 2 tables in the database (Employee and Department). Each employee belongs to a department and a department can have multiple employees.

I am displaying a grid with the list of employees. The grid looks like this

[image]

Now I am trying to show the Department as a dropdownlist which shows all the departments and selects the one the Employee belongs to. I cannot find a clear example to do this. This is my code

// Employee Controller

```
public ActionResult Kendo()
{
  var departments = db.Departments.ToList();
  ViewData["departments"] = departments;

  var employees = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Department);
  return View(employees.ToList());
}
```

The view

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<MVCProj.Models.Employee>)Model) 
.Name("KendoGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(e => e.EmployeeId);
    columns.Bound(e => e.FirstName);
    columns.Bound(e => e.LastName);
    columns.Bound(e => e.Gender);
    columns.Bound(e => e.City);
    columns.Bound(e => e.Department.DepartmentName).EditorTemplateName("DepartmentEditor").Title("Department").Width(250);
})
.Pageable() //Enable the paging.
.Sortable() //Enable the sorting.
.Scrollable()
)
```

DepartmentEditor Template

```
@using System.Collections

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("Department")
      .DataValueField("DepartmentId")
      .DataTextField("DepartmentName")
      .BindTo((IEnumerable)ViewData["departments"])
```

)

What am I doing wrong here?

Also once this is done I will be adding Add, Update and Delete buttons. So if there is a clear example that shows how to do it please post that also.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the Foreign Key Column demo https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/foreignkeycolumn